# How just to configure GoogleAnalyticsBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I configured a [GoogleAnalyticsBundle](https://github.com/Happyr/GoogleAnalyticsBundle) and [DoctrineCacheBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle) as saying in the configuration in each of them,but i got this error:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
The service "happyr.google.analytics.data_fetcher" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine_cache.providers.apc_cache".
```

Comment: Try [Debugging Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#debugging-services) and running `php bin/console debug:container`, or if you are using a version of Symfony older than 2.6, try `php app/console container:debug` and seeing if the Doctrine service exists.

Comment: Can you show us your `doctrine_cache` config block?

Comment: Many Thankx Jason for answering i will see

Comment: Sorry showing config.yml

Comment: #doctrine_cache:
  #providers:
    #file:
      #file_system:
        #extension: '.token'
        #directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/var/storage/fs_cache/'
    #my_apc_metadata_cache:
            #type: apc
            #namespace: metadata_cache_ns
    #my_apc_query_cache:
            #namespace: query_cache_ns
            #apc: ~